# Haskell function definition not working as expected

Tags: haskell

I am new to functional programming and Haskell. Trying to learn it. Not sure what is wrong with the following definition:

Function definition in test.h

```
drop5 [a]  = drop 5 [a]
```

Trying to use this function I get Program error

```
$:load test.h
$drop5 [2,3,4,5,6,7,8]
Program error: pattern match failure: drop5 [2,3,4,5,6,7,8]
$:t drop5
drop5 :: [a] -> [a]
```

When I change the definition to following it works; meaning it takes a list and drops first 5 elements of the list

```
drop5 ns = drop 5 ns
```

And in this case when print type I see:

```
$:t drop5
drop5 :: [a] -> [a]
```

I am not sure why is the first definition different than second? And what does the error "Program error: pattern match failure means"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the first definition, `[a]` is a pattern that only matches a list of exactly one element, and that element becomes known as `a` in the right part of the rule.

Thus, you define the function as only accepting singleton lists.

Moreover, dropping 5 elements from a list that only has one obviously results in an empty list (as does dropping of any positive number of elements).

Comment: That makes sense. Thank you!! I tried drop5 [2] and that did not return any error.

Answer (score 4):

Your function definition:

```
drop5 [a] = drop 5 [a]
```

Specifies that the clause only "fires" for lists with exactly *one* element. Indeed in a function definition `[a]` is **not the type** of the parameter, it is **a pattern**. The pattern `[a]` means that we are working with a list with exactly one element.

If you compile with `-Wall` you will get:

```
<interactive>:1:1: warning: [-Wincomplete-patterns]
    Pattern match(es) are non-exhaustive
    In an equation for ‘drop5’:
        Patterns not matched:
            []
            (_:_:_)
```

The compiler/interpreter thus produces a warning that two patterns are not covered: one for an *empty* list, and one for a list with *two or more elements*.

Comment: Interesting. How does compiler know if it is a pattern or parameter? Also I am using hugs98 to start with (this was recommended on edx Intro to functional programming course). I am not sure how to compile a file here.

Comment: @patronus: a parameter *is* a pattern. You can however - in the head - use a pattern. In that case the line is "fired" if the pattern matches. Pattern matching is one of the aspects that almost all functional programming languages share.

Answer (score 2):

`[a]` is telling Haskell that there is only one element in a list, while `ns` tells Haskell that it could be anything (even a boolean if you want) until you finish the function and it identifies the output and input type. You could also explicitly tell Haskell what the input and output type is by adding this above that line:

```
drop5 :: [Integer] -> [Integer]
```

Which could be found by doing `:t drop5` in GHCI.

Also, on a side note, this code can be reduced. By changing it to:

```
drop5 = drop 5
```

This may not make sense to you right now, but as you learn more you should learn that all Haskell functions take one argument.